# Angular - Display negative value in parentheses and maintain 'type: number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working with a chart of percentages, and I want to format the negative numbers to be in parentheses instead of with a negative sign. I can find how to do this with a pipe... but ONLY if I have the currency pipe that then transforms the number type to a string. Is there a way to keep the type a number AND substitute parentheses for the negative sign? Here is the pipe:

```
export class MinusToParensPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
        return value.charAt(0) === '-' ?
            '(' + value.substring(1, value.length) + ')' :
            value;
    }
}
```

Comment: A quick fix may be adding a class to the html container that sets :before/:after with content of ()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a Pipe is not necessary, try something like:

HTML

```
<p [ngClass]="{'setPerens' : isNegitive(YourNumericalValue)}">{{YourNumericalValue | negToPos }}</p>
```

SASS

```
.setPerens {
 :before {
  content: '(';
 :after {
  content: ')';
 }
}
```

.TS

```
isNegitive(val: number): boolean {
 if (val < 0) {
  return true;
 } else {
  return false
 }
}
```

**EDIT 1:**

To get rid of the minus, you could now use a Pipe like so:

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'negToPos'
})
export class NegToPosPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val: number): number {
    return Math.abs(val);
  }
}
```

Comment: That gets very close and works essentially... but it leaves the minus sign. I need for it to be ONLY parentheses WITHOUT the minus like this (5.6).

Comment: @Meg, take a look at the update. A simple pipe transform on the UI value could get you there.

Comment: Why create a pipe to remove the '-' symbol?  Why not then complete the pipe and make it add the parenthesis aswel?  This prevents me having to add the `isNegative` method to all pages that I want to use it on.

Answer (score 0):

This is rather easy.  Why not take the value that is sent to the pipe, and add the parenthesis based on that?

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'negativeParenthesis'
})
export class NegativeParenthesisPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: number): unknown {
     const formattedValue = formatNumber(value, 'en', '1.0-2');
     value >= 0 ? formattedValue : `(${formattedValue.replace('-', '')})`;
  }

}
```

So here we check if the value is greater or equal to 0.  If it is, just return that in a number formatter (provided by Angular).  Otherwise return it in parenthesis and remove the '-' symbol from the formatted value.  One line.

We add the pipe to the `app.module` and never worry about adding anything else again.  We can just use it